# QEMU: blacklisting kernel module doesn't prevent it from showing up as available in `lspci`

Tags: kernel-module, qemu, blacklist

I'm working in QEMU, and attempting to see if the guest can still use a PCI device without the corresponding kernel module loaded.

To start, `lspci -v` shows the following:

```
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation ########## PIIX4 ACPI (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc Qemu virtual machine
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 9
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4
```

Before attempting to remove `i2c_piix4`, `lsmod` confirmed that it was loaded. To remove it, I edited `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and added the line `blacklist i2c_piix4`, then called `sudo update-initramfs -u` and `reboot`ed. Now, the module has disappeared from `lsmod`, but is still listed under `lspci`. This is still true after `modprobe -r`. Have I properly blacklisted it, or is there another step I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lspci` shows the hardware on the pci bus - no matter if a corresponding kernel module is loaded or not.

To remove a device you can do this in the qemu monitor by id or locate it with `info qtree` and `info qom-tree` and remove it with `device_del`.

But removing your specific device is not supported on the `ps-i440fx` architecture.

```
(qemu) info qom-tree /machine/unattached/device[24]
/device[24] (PIIX4_PM)
  /piix4-pm[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /acpi-cpu-hotplug[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /acpi-evt[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /acpi-tmr[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /apm-io[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /bus master container[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /bus master[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /acpi-pci-hotplug[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /pm-smbus[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /acpi-gpe0[0] (qemu:memory-region)
  /i2c (i2c-bus)
  /acpi-cnt[0] (qemu:memory-region)
(qemu)
(qemu) device_del /machine/unattached/device[24]
Device 'PIIX4_PM' does not support hotplugging
(qemu)
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that since it was appearing on the line "kernel modules" in `lspci` that it was still loaded.